# Swashbuckle - swagger documentation of returned response?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle would not generate swagger.json with an output of "UserCreateResponse", how do you fix this?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]UserCreate Request)
    {
        UserCreateResponse response = new UserCreateResponse();

        //do something here

        // returns UserCreateResponse with http status code 200
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

You can't do this, because its not going to return the http status code, 200,400,401 etc

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<UserCreateResponse> Update([FromBody]UserCreate Request)
    {
        UserCreateResponse response = new UserCreateResponse();

        //do something here

        // returns UserCreateResponse
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify the response type with the following attribute:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(UserCreateResponse), 200)]
```

Answer (score 16):

### **The below solution works only for Swashbuckle versions prior to V6.0!**

**From V6.0 onwards `SwaggerResponse` isn't supported anymore, see [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/159).**

---

Another variant is the use of the `SwaggerResponse` attribute, which also allows to provide an additional description:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "UserDTO", typeof(UserDTO))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var result = await UserRepo.GetAsync(key);
    ...
    return Ok(result);
}
```

which produces output as shown here:

[image] 
[image]

It's also possible to omit the type to document other status codes which do not return an entity:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "no data found")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "requiered request headers not found")]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately `SwaggerResponse` is removed in more recent versions of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. `ProducesResponseType` is the way to go, with optional XML comments if you still want the string explanation (read more about that [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/159)).

Comment: Thanks @JimAho for the information, I didn't know that. I've updated my answer to let readers know.

Comment: I just simply solved the status code 200 to 400 while changing the return type from return Ok(json_structure); to return new JsonResult(json_structure); in the exception handler, and the issue is well solved ! .

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET Core 2.1, using [ActionResult<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types#actionresultt-type) would be the recommended approach to specify the returned type. It gets picked by Swashbuckle and also adds type checks at the compilation.

You also can add description on the response via XML comment ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?tabs=visual-studio#describe-response-types)).

So for the OP's example it would be

```
/// <summary> 
///     Update the user 
/// </summary>
/// <response code="200"> User's data </response>
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserCreateResponse>> Update(...) 
{
   ...
}
```